# how to get R,G,B from a image list in python

Tags: image, rgb

i have tried this

```
train_path=r"D:/Study/DL/all-photos/train" 
train_images=[cv2.imread(train_path+str(i)+".jpg") for i in range(train_size)]
y_train_red=[img[:,:,0] for img in train_images]
y_train_blue=[img[:,:,1] for img in train_images]
y_train_green=[img[:,:,2] for img in train_images]
```

but in the y_train_red i get this error

'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

how to fix it?

Comment: Please try to load one image by specifying it’s full path and loading it as a color image. Look up help for cv2.imread for information on the 2nd parameter.
Also note that OpenCV reads image as BGR and not RGB

Answer (score 1):

yeah the path was slightly wrong
sorry for the inconvience